# Как получить название файла, в котором находится вызываемая функция? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно получить название файла, в котором находится вызываемая функция.
Пример:

В файле `my_func.py` находится функция func, обернутая в декоратор:

```
from decorator import my_decorator

@my_decorator
def my_func():
   pass

my_func()
```

В файле `decorator.py` находится следующий декоратор:

```
def my_decorator(func):
   def wrapper():
      print(<Тут должно быть название my_func.py>)
      func()
   return wrapper
```

Comment: модули не только в `.py` файлах могут находиться. Питон модули могут быть в zip-архиве, egg, заморожены (py2exe, PyInstaller,cx_Freeze), доступны через символическую ссылку. Посмотрите [как `get_script_dir()` реализована](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import inspect

def my_decorator(func):
   def wrapper():
      print(inspect.getfile(func))
      func()
   return wrapper
```

на 2.х работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_decorator(func):
   def wrapper():
      print(func.__module__)
      func()
   return wrapper
```

Comment: Пробовал. Печатает не название файла, а __main__

Comment: [Странно.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KyoG.png)